# Definir um ArrayField de DateFields

Tags: banco-de-dados, array, django, datetime, django-2.0

Preciso armazenar várias datas em um model Django (estou usando a versão 2.1), consegui criando vários campos, assim:

```
date1 = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Data da parcela 1")
date2 = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Data da parcela 2")
...
```

Mas isso não é muito prático, inclusive a quantidade de datas (datas de parcelas) deve ser variável. Pesquisando vi que existe ArrayField e tentei o seguinte:

```
dates = ArrayField(
    models.DateField(null=True, blank=True),
)
```

Mas quando rodo a migration aparece o erro:

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "dates" is of type date[] but default expression is of type integer
>   HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

Por que está falando que o default é integer? Alguém sabe uma maneira melhor de fazer isso?

Obs: Deixar o default como datetime.now seria ruim, tem algum tipo de "datetime.null"ou algo assim?

Comment: Só pra confirmar: Você tá usando um banco postgres?

Comment: Anyway, uma outra alternativa seria tentar setar também para o arrayfield um "blank=True"

Comment: sim, postgres @mazulo

Comment: Beleza, vamos tentar então definir algo como: dates = ArrayField(models.DateField(null=True, blank=True), blank=True)